# Why did Jack destroy Beckett's ship?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*, why did Jack destroy Beckett's ship when making the deal to lead Beckett to Shipwreck Cove? If they made a deal, how was Beckett supposed to follow Jack?

Comment: Are pirates known for their trustworthiness?

Answer (score 2):

He *wasn't* supposed to follow Captain Jack - or at least, not until the *Endeavour* was repaired.

Captain Jack made the deal with Beckett to save his own skin, and then immediately reneged on it, sabotaging Beckett's ship and escaping. Captain Jack does that sort of thing over and over again throughout the entire series.